# How to get data for Realtime DB Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that contains a node called "chats_users" where all user names are recorded to ensure uniqueness. However, I don't understand how to check for duplicates in this node when the registration button is pressed. [DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glDT3.png)

```
buttonReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String email, password, name;
        email = String.valueOf(editTextEmail.getText());
        password = String.valueOf(editTextPassword.getText());
        name = String.valueOf(editTextName.getText());

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((password))) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (task.isSuccessful() & password.length() > 6 & Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches() & !isName) {
                            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (currentUser != null) {
                                String userId = currentUser.getUid();

                                Map<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
                                userData.put("email", email);
                                userData.put("name", name);

                                usersRef.child(userId).setValue(userData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        namesRef.child(name).setValue(name);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I tried asking ChatGPT, but it only throws one method through DataChange, which runs only after the main loop. I just need to check if the username the user is trying to enter already exists in my database, and if it does, ask them to enter another one

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. So do you need to check if a user already exists? If yes, show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.